# Trying to loop through two elements of a push array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to teach myself javascript and for my first small project I am trying to animate by looping two images from the array depending on situation. Ie. a win scenario would loop heroIdle and heroWave. After a few hours of searching I have turned here in hope of any guidance.

```
image.push({ id: "heroIdle", src: "heroIdle.png" });
image.push({ id: "heroWave", src: "heroWave.png" });
image.push({ id: "heroStomp", src: "heroStomp" });
```

I have tried to simply return `image["heroIdle"];` and still nothing is displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post more code, especially of parts that dont work as intended, but context helps too. Also: what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Please post a fiddle

Comment: if you want to return the `src` property, I would suggest not pushing an object into `image`, but instead use `image['heroidle'] = "heroIdle.png"`. Then `return image["heroIdle"]` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't even looped throught the array if you use `image["heroIdle"]` directly, and use the `id` as key not its value because `heroIdle` is a value here,  use a loop like this and use `image[i]["id"]` to get the value of the `id`:

```js
var image = [];
image.push({
  id: "heroIdle",
  src: "heroIdle.png"
});
image.push({
  id: "heroWave",
  src: "heroWave.png"
});
image.push({
  id: "heroStomp",
  src: "heroStomp"
});

for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
  // to show both the id and the src
  alert(image[i]["id"]+".src = "+image[i]["src"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that an array is index based, which means you have to access it with an integer index. For example:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray.push("hello");
myArray.push("world");
myArray[0]; // "hello"
```

So, you need to find loop through the array and find the index of the element with a particular id

```
image.push({ id: "heroIdle", src: "heroIdle.png" });
image.push({ id: "heroWave", src: "heroWave.png" });
image.push({ id: "heroStomp", src: "heroStomp" });

for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
   if (image[i].id === 'heroIdle') {
       var heroIdleImage = image[i];
       // do something with heroIdleImage
   }
}
```

Alternatively you could use an object, which is similar to an array but you can also use strings for keys:

```
var image = {};
image.heroIdle = 'heroIdle.png';
image.heroWave = 'heroWave.png';
image['heroStomp'] = 'heroStomp.png' // you can access objects using dot or bracket notation

var heroStompSrc = image.heroStomp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
var image =[];
image.push({ id: "heroIdle", src: "heroIdle.png" });
image.push({ id: "heroWave", src: "heroWave.png" });
image.push({ id: "heroStomp", src: "heroStomp" });

for(var i =0; i< image.length; i++){
    if (image[i].id === 'heroIdle'){
       alert(image[i].src);
    }
}
```

demo in [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yfdn49ap/1/)

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding you want to show images on particular Image

```
var image=[];
image.push({ id: "heroIdle", src: "heroIdle.png" });
image.push({ id: "heroWave", src: "heroWave.png" });
image.push({ id: "heroStomp", src: "heroStomp" });

for each (i in image) {

  document.getElementById("myImg").src = i.src;
  }
```

Comment: Are you aware this doesn't work? I would recommend testing your answers before submitting them.